# Why stream redirection operator &>> not working in SUSE linux?

Tags: linux, shell, suse

My shell-script is failing on SUSE Linux as the stream-redirection operator I have used (&>>) is not working there, (But it is working fine in Other distributions). How can I correct this. Also I would like to know the standard way of doing the same which is supported by all Distributions?

Comment: Redirection operators depend on the shell you are using (bash, sh, ksh, csh, etc...). What shell are you using?

Comment: I have not specified any shell. It must be using default.

Comment: I cannot guess. Do you get any result with something as `echo $SHELL`? Or maybe `echo $shell`?

Comment: By `&>> file`, do you mean `>> file 2>&1`? See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29#Redirecting_to_and_from_the_standard_file_handles).

Comment: yes. I want to append output from std:out and std:error to a file.

Comment: Most linux distributions, including Suse, use bash as a default shell. So for some reasons the user you are connected with uses a non-bourne shell. Try command `echo $SHELL` to check this.

Comment: That machine is not available to me at this point of time. I will check this whenever it is available.

Comment: And what about the shell you were using until there on the other distributions? Can you check it? `>>&` seems to me to be a csh redirection.

Comment: @jdarthenay, I was not able to check the shell at that time as well, So I am not sure. I will update as soon as I get a chance to access that machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command you were using should mean you were using bourne shell:

```
ls &>> file
```

this command should redirect both stdout and stderr at the end of file.
Another way to write it, again with a bourne shell could be:

```
ls >> file 2>&1
```

However it seems to me this way to write the command will be recognized by more shells, I think for instance ksh will recognize the second form but not the first.

With csh or a csh-like shell you will need to use this syntax:

```
ls >>& file
```

Edit: I was confused because depending on the shell you can use `&>>` or `>>&` which are not the same.